# Can i get an access to a flash player`s events pool?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I want to trace every event on every object, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

The one way is to simply override its dispatchEvent function:

```
override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean
{
    // Do something with event.
    return super.dispatchEvent( event );
}
```

The problem, however, is that this does not always work -- sometimes dispatchEvent is not called if a child object does something.  It also will not work if you are unwilling to create a special class for each instance.

Another alternative is to iterate through an array of different event types:

```
var evtTypes:Array = [ MouseEvent.CLICK, MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, 
                       MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN...
                       Event.ADDED, Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE... etc.];

for( var i:int = 0; i < evtTypes.length; i++ )
{
    target.addEventListener( evtTypes[ i ], trace );
}
```

The problem with this method is that you'll not be able to capture custom events, only the events you have in your list.  I would definitely recommend the second method for most learning and debugging problems.

I suppose a more important question, however, is "What do you want to do with these events?"  Most of the documentation lists all of the events an object will dispatch: if you scroll down in the [MovieClip](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) documentation, you'll see an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own registry and access it that way. So yes, there is a way to do it, but no, not easily.